# What is wrong with this Laravel 5 response?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I need to return custom headers but it's not working for me.

For example

```
$content = view('my.view')

return (new Response($content, 304))->header('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
```

and

```
return response($content, 304)->header('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
```

and even so

```
new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response($content,304,['Content-Type'=>'text/plain']);`
```

I just want render view with custom headers, but in browser I get response code 200 and content-type `text/html`.

Comment: Where are you calling this from?

Comment: are you you using Illuminate\Http\Response; in your file

Comment: yes! I add `use Illuminate\Http\Response; ` in header on my controller,
maybe problem in http code with headers, but the following line return plain/text
`return response('foo', 400, ['Content-Type' => 'text/plain']);`